# Xcodeでビルドが出来なくなってしまいました

Tags: xcode

## 困っていること

XCODEを8から9.2にバージョンアップしたのですが、
以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されビルドが出来ない状態になってしまいました。
ググったのですが、理由が分かりません。
どなたかお助けいただけないでしょうか？

```
Build operation failed without specifying any errors. 
Individual build tasks may have failed for unknown reasons.
```

※ Carhage, Pods, DerivedData のディレクトリを削除して、Clean Build Folderを行ってから再ビルドしましたが駄目でした。

## 環境

XCODE:9.2
CocoaPods:1.3.1
Carthage:0.28.0

Answer (score 1):

下記のページ
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94321

によると、
CocoaPods:1.3.1 から、1.2.1　にダウングレードすることにより回避できたようです。
試してみる価値があるかもしれません。